# JSP -if != null conditions on parameter

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, jsp, is-empty

I a have jsp form page which get parameters an I need to check if one of them != null ,I have tried to write the condition but its not working:
It went to the if block and not to the else block any way(display null or the value respectively).

The code:

```
</div>
            <div class="grid_8 row12 td_style_fieldValue">
            <% if(!userData7.isEmpty()){%>
            <div id="personalId" class="data_style_payment" disabled="disabled" ><%=userData7%></div>
            <%}else{%>
            <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" id="personalId" name="personalId" maxlength="9" dir="ltr" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="limitInput(this,9)" onchange="return validatePersonalId()"/>
            <%}%>
            </div>
```

"userData7" is a parameter with value.
please assist me what am I missing here ?does the if:else syntax is right?
tnx

Comment: Do it like your question title.  if(userData7 != null)

Comment: Finally it worked like that: </div>
   <div class="grid_8 row12 td_style_fieldValue">
   <% if(userData7.equals("null")){%>
   <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" id="personalId" name="personalId" maxlength="9" dir="ltr" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="limitInput(this,9)" onchange="return validatePersonalId()"/>
   <%}else{%>
   <div id="personalId" class="data_style_payment" disabled="disabled" ><%=userData7%></div>
   <%}%>
   </div>

Comment: I guess it just gets the empty value as a 'NULL' string therefore userData7.equals("null") worked.